# How to show KaTex - output on GitHub README.md file?

Tags: github, markdown, readme, katex

I am completely new to markdown and I am using typora to edit and create markdown files.In my editor I have using the following code

```
$$
\textcolor{aqua}{\boxed{\pmb{\mathscr{\text{Statement 1} \Rightarrow\begin{cases}
&\text{Statement 2 }\Omicron(anything)\\
&\text{Statement 3 }\Gamma(anything)
\end{cases}}}}}
$$
```

which shows the following result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ2c5.png)

but in github readme preview it shows like

```
$$ \textcolor{aqua}{\boxed{\mathscr{\pmb{\text{Statement 1} \Rightarrow [\begin{cases} &\text{Statement  }\Omicron (anything)\ &\text{Statement 3 }\Gamma (anything)\ \end{cases}]}}}} $$
```

Is there any way to achieve desired output so that it shows like what the given picture shows.
I can use image instead of using katex codeblock. But I don't want to use image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub itself, through its [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec)](https://github.github.com/gfm/) does not support [Katex](https://katex.org/)

You would need for your GitHub repositories to be a **[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)** project in order to include for instance a Jekyll plugin like [`linjer/jekyll-katex`](https://github.com/linjer/jekyll-katex), in order for those pages to represent a Katex section properly.
See also "[How to Create A Jekyll Page With KaTeX](https://nealde.github.io/blog/2017/10/20/How-to-make-a-local-Jekyll-website/)" from **[Neal Dawson-Elli](https://nealde.github.io/about/)**.